# Java codingbat help - withoutString

Tags: java, string

I'm using codingbat.com to get some java practice in.  One of the String problems, 'withoutString' is as follows:

Given two strings, base and remove, return a version of the base string where all instances of the remove string have been removed (not case sensitive). 
You may assume that the remove string is length 1 or more. Remove only non-overlapping instances, so with "xxx" removing "xx" leaves "x".
This problem can be found at:  http://codingbat.com/prob/p192570

As you can see from the the dropbox-linked screenshot below, all of the runs pass except for three and a final one called "other tests." The thing is, even though they are marked as incorrect, my output matches exactly the expected output for the correct answer.

Here's a screenshot of my output:

[image: Screenshot of my output]

And here's the code I'm using:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) { 
  String result = "";
  int i = 0;

  for(; i < base.length()-remove.length();){
    if(!(base.substring(i,i+remove.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(remove))){
      result = result + base.substring(i,i+1);
      i++;
    }
    else{
      i = i + remove.length();
    }
    if(result.startsWith(" ")) result = result.substring(1);
    if(result.endsWith(" ") && base.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) result = result.substring(0,result.length()-1); 
  }
  if(base.length()-i <= remove.length() && !(base.substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase(remove))){
      result = result + base.substring(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daemon

your code works.  Thanks for the regex explanation.  Though dansalmo pointed out that codingbat is displaying the intended output incorrectly, I through in some extra lines to your code to unnecessarily account for the double spaces with the following:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove){ 
  String result = base.replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, "");

  for(int i = 0; i < result.length()-1;){
    if(result.substring(i,i+2).equals("  ")){
      result = result.replace(result.substring(i,i+2), " ");
    }
    else i++;
  }

  if(result.startsWith(" ")) result = result.substring(1);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your solution IS failing AND there is a display bug in coding bat.

The correct output should be:

```
 withoutString("This is a FISH", "IS") -> "Th  a FH"
```

Yours is:

```
 withoutString("This is a FISH", "IS") -> "Th a FH"
```

Yours fails because it is removing spaces, but also, coding bat does not display the correct expected and run output string due to HTML removing extra spaces.

This recursive solution passes all tests:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
    int remIdx = base.toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
    if (remIdx == -1)
        return base;
    return base.substring(0, remIdx ) + 
           withoutString(base.substring(remIdx + remove.length()) , remove);
}
```

Here is an example of an optimal iterative solution.  It has more code than the recursive solution but is faster since far fewer function calls are made.

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
    int remIdx = 0;
    int remLen = remove.length();
    remove = remove.toLowerCase();
    while (true) {
        remIdx = base.toLowerCase().indexOf(remove);
        if (remIdx == -1)
            break;
        base = base.substring(0, remIdx) + base.substring(remIdx + remLen);
    }
    return base; 
}
```

Comment: wow are you kidding me? I HAD the extra space in initially and busted my hump trying to get it to match, but probably had others that were failing before i cleaned those up.  I'm too tired to try now, but what you say makes sense and I'll sleep easier taking your word for it.  Well.. at least all that extra effort removing double spaces between words got me some practice.

Comment: @dansalmo:  Is a recursive a function that loops by continually nesting every time the function is called within itself?  If so, in this case when calling the return the first time, it's taking base's substring from 0 to the first case of 'remove'. Then the concatenated reminder is a call to the function. Does this mean it jumps to the the first line of the function "int remIDx = 0" and proceeds down until it hits the function within the function within the function and keeps nesting until remIdx == -1, in which case it breaks?

Comment: @dansalmo: in the iterative solution, the condition for while to iterate is (true).  What exactly is it testing to be true or false?

Comment: @Stuart Kuredjian, in the iterative solution, the `if (remIdx == -1)` test is what breaks out of the loop when `.indexOf()` returns `-1` meaning the `remove` string was not found, otherwise `while(true)` would loop always.

Comment: @Stuart Kuredjian, yes, a recursive function loops by nesting every time the function calls itself.  It will continue to nest deeper until the base case, `if (remIdx == -1)` is met, then each nested level will return it's result to the previous level.  It does not call the iterative version, they are completely different and stand alone solutions.

Comment: @dansalmo thanks... I understand that it's the if (remIdx == -1) test that causes the loop to break.  I'm just not clear on what the while (true) condition is testing to be true or false.  what would be an example of the  while condition being false?  is the true/false referring to the the code inside the while statement being true or false?  If so, isn't it already being tested with the -1?

Comment: The `(true)` part is the test.  It is always `true`, so the `while` condition is never `false`.  The only way out of the `while` loop in this case is via the `break`.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran your code in an IDE. **It compiles correctly and matches all tests shown on codingbat**. There must be some bug with codingbat's test cases.

If you are curious, this problem can be solved with a single line of code:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
     return base.replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, ""); //String#replaceAll(String, String) with case insensitive regex.
}
```

**Regex explaination**:

The first argument taken by String#replaceAll(String, String) is what is known as a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or "*regex*" for short.

Regex is a powerful tool to perform pattern matching within Strings. In this case, the regular expression being used is (assuming that `remove` is equal to `IS`):

`(?i)IS`

This particular expression has two parts: `(?i)` and `IS`.

`IS` matches the string `"IS"` exactly, nothing more, nothing less.

`(?i)` is simply a flag to tell the regex engine to ignore case.

With `(?i)IS`, all of: `IS`, `Is`, `iS` and `is` will be matched.

As an addition, this is (almost) equivalent to the regular expressions: `(IS|Is|iS|is)`, `(I|i)(S|s)` and `[Ii][Ss]`.

**EDIT**

Turns out that your output is not correct and is failing as expected. See: [dansalmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20665773/2081889).

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand.  I'm also using an IDE to work through problems offline and all my cases match correctly.  As mentioned, even IN codingbat my output matches coding bat's intended output.  If you look at the screen shot i linked, this will be made clearer.  The only reason I'm hesitant on saying that codingbat is bugged, is because i've run into this with other problems and after simplifying the code, all the runs passed. I'll try yours, but I'm still curious. (**Also I'm new here, is it acceptable to reply as an answer, or like this as a comment?**)

Comment: your code works except for one of the initial problems I had of it double counting a space if an entire word is removed (it counts the space before and after the word).  I resolved this in my initial code, but I'm wondering if you have a simpler way to exclude a secondary space.

Comment: @ Daemon  I'm trying to decipher the syntax of .replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, "").  I'm assuming that the first part is what it is looking to replace and the part after the , is what the first part is being replaced by. So in this case "(?i)" and remove are replaced with "".  First, am I correct in understanding the syntax?  and second, what is "(?i)"

Comment: @ Daemon I got around the double spacing by throwing in a second .replaceAll which replaces "  "  with " ".  i.e. base.replaceAll("  ", " ");  Would you have done the same, or is there something simpler?  Also still not sure what "(?i)" is implying.  Removing it, ignores case insensitivity, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @StuartKuredjian I've edited the code to handle unnecessary whitespace (although I'd argue that such functionality is not part of the requirements).

Comment: @StuartKuredjian `(?i)` tells the regex engine that the following regex should be case insensitive. If you're not familiar with regex, I'd look into it. It is an incredibly powerful tool **when used correctly**. I emphasise as many view regex as a magic fix-all, when really it is simply a tool with a specific purpose.

Comment: This solution fails for `withoutString("Hi HoHo", "Ho") → "Hi "` with an output of `"Hi"`.

Comment: Do not add the trim() -- this removes the leading/trailing whitespace which will fail you for `withoutString("Hi HoHo", "Ho") → "Hi "`

`return base.replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, "");`

Comment: @Daemon Thanks for the regex flag explanation.  Just some final clarification though.  if (?i) is flag for ignoring case-sensitivity, (a) why is the syntax (?i) + regex as opposed to (?i)regex?  The + to me implies concatenation. (b) why does the flag require quotes around it?  (c) is there any logic to the ?i or is it just an arbitrary combination of keystrokes initially implemented by those who created the language?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
        String temp = base.replaceAll(remove, "");
        String temp2 = temp.replaceAll(remove.toLowerCase(), "");
        return temp2.replaceAll(remove.toUpperCase(), "");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my solution

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
   final int rLen=remove.length();
   final int bLen=base.length();
   String op="";

   for(int i = 0; i < bLen;)
   {
        if(!(i + rLen > bLen) && base.substring(i, i + rLen).equalsIgnoreCase(remove))
        {
            i +=rLen;
            continue;
        }
        op += base.substring(i, i + 1);
        i++;
   }

   return op;   

}
```

[image]

Something things go really weird on codingBat this is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding to a previous solution, but using a StringBuilder for better practice. Most credit goes to Anirudh.

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
    //create a constant integer the size of remove.length();
    final int rLen=remove.length();
    //create a constant integer the size of base.length();
    final int bLen=base.length();
    //Create an empty string;
    StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder();
    //Create the for loop.
    for(int i = 0; i < bLen;)
    {
      //if the remove string lenght we are looking for is not less than the base length
      // and the base substring equals the remove string.
      if(!(i + rLen > bLen) && base.substring(i, i + rLen).equalsIgnoreCase(remove))
      {
        //Increment by the remove length, and skip adding it to the string.
        i +=rLen;
        continue;
      }
      //else, we add the character at i to the string builder.
      op.append(base.charAt(i));
      //and increment by one.
      i++;
    }
  //We return the string.
  return op.toString();   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's solution is the most efficient one, however I have another solution that is a naive one and it works.

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  String returnString = base;
  while(returnString.toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase())!=-1){
    int start = returnString.toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
    int end = remove.length();
    returnString = returnString.substring(0, start) + returnString.substring(start+end);
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove){ 
    return base.replace(remove,"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  return base.replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, "");
}
```